# Need a PDF with multiple current date fields

Tags: date, pdf-generation, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I have a checklist form I'm building in Adobe LiveCycle ES2 that our IT department uses and they need it to have Monday-Friday on it and each day needs to have a current date field that autofills and becomes read only once it is populated, but it only needs to populate that day. Basically, on Monday, they open the form, the date for Monday gets populated, but Tuesday-Friday stays empty, they come in on Tuesday and open the form and Tuesday's date is now also populated. Does this make sense? Is this something that is fairly simple? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I know exactly what you really want to achieve. If I made some wrong assumptions let me know.

You can get week day using getDay() method on JavaScript Date object. It returns int value 0-6 where 0 means Sunday, 1 Monday, .. 6 Saturday.

Assume you have one Date/Time field for every week day. To make it read-only set their type to protected (in Object->Value toolbox). In each of them put the following code in initialize event. Don't forget to adjust *if* condition for every field

```
var d = new Date();
if (d.getDay() == 6){ //checking whether today is saturday
  this.rawValue = util.printd("yyyy-mm-dd", new Date());
}
```